# How to implement ReactJs in Electron application?

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'm starting an application in Electron, but let's say I did in two parts, one part, Electron, the configuration is ok, except that the other part I did in other files using ReactJS, which is relatively ready, missing adjustments. My question is the following, how do I make this part I did in ReactJS I implement in Electron? (My English is bad, translated by google translator, sorry).

I will not be able to show the codes as it would be complicated, but to try to make it easier I will put some prints of the folders.

**First image.** This is the folder where the Electron is, and the main file is the `main.js` which is where I set the Electron, the htlms say that would be irrelevant for such a doubt. And the `package.json` will put in another print.

**Second image.** I got to install the `React` but as I do not know how to do it then I did not go ahead.

**Third image.** That's React's "public", who would say that it is irrelevant to such a problem as well.

**Fourth image.** And this is where the React part works. In App.js but specifically in render, it would be another Electron browserWindow. The `index.js` would be the "main", I'll be putting a print. And `registerServiceWorking.js` I will say that I do not know very well what it is for.

**Fifth image.** And this as I said, is the index, where it imports things (do not know the correct term for this case).

I had to put it as a code because it was bugging

```
First: [prntscr.com/js21oa][1]
Second: [prntscr.com/js22kh][1]
Third: [prntscr.com/js22yx][1]
Fourth: [prntscr.com/js23a3][1]
Fifth: [prntscr.com/js24nb][1]
```

And to make it clear, I'm new to such issues and StackOverflow, sorry if the formatting was bad and the images, I only got through the external site. And if anyone wants me to clarify something that I have not made clear, just say that I will be clarifying. And I apologize if you have not understood anything else. I hope you have understood. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess You have created a react app and you want to make it a desktop app with electron. i Dont have enough reputation to make a comment to clarify things. I will show you a sample code of what i have done in my react electron desktop app, i hope it helps. i assume you have already installed electron and all other needed packages.

main.js

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')


  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {

  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

and in index.html mine is in root folder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body class="fix-header card-no-border">
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
      <div id="root"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="build/static/js/main.7f2e4ee8.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But you dont need import React?

Comment: I think it would look like this: import react from 'react', in main.js

Comment: which main file are you referring to?, This is for electron. in index.html the main file i am referring to is the react code, i am using a build version which is that "build/static/js/main.js". if you want to directly use react with electron you can checkout electron compiler

Comment: Is that so, in my App.js file I did with ReactJS, and wanted to pass this file to Electron, because in Electron I have certain settings to make the application.

Comment: I am try implement my React files in this repository: https://github.com/csepulv/electron-with-create-react-app

Comment: If I can, I will tell you!!

Comment: your electron starter is my main.js file and your public/index.html is my root index.html

Comment: Have look at this : https://github.com/shanshaji/electron-music-player. I have used react and made a very simple electron music player. hope it helps.